# Is Guid of a User in ActiveDirectory Nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and here's my Model:

```
public class AdContactInfo
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Then using this code snippet, I'm trying to search for list of users:

```
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(principal) { DisplayName = term + "*" }))
{
    var result = searcher.FindAll();
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        list.Add(new AdContactInfo
            { FullName = item.Name, 
              Guid = item.Guid });
    }
}
```

I'm surprised that the line `Guid = item.Guid` has an error saying `item.Guid` is Nullable and cannot be converted to `Guid`.

After some research, I didn't find any result that says Guid of User in ActiveDirectory can contain null. However, I found an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) that says if I set the `ContextType` to Machine it will always return to null.

I want to know why it is Nullable.

Comment: The `Guid` property on the `UserPrincipal` class is inherited from the base `Principal` class, where it's defined as `Nullable<Guid>`. That's just the way it is - you need to deal with this. Why this was chosen to be defined as *nullable* - I don't know. From my experience with AD, all the objects you come across that descend from `Principal` - groups, computers, users etc. - will have a GUID assigned

Answer (score 1):

The `Guid` property on the `UserPrincipal` class is inherited from the base `Principal` class, where it's defined as `Nullable<Guid>`. That's just the way it is - you need to deal with this.

**Why** this was chosen to be defined as nullable - I don't know. From my experience with AD, all the objects you come across that descend from `Principal` - groups, computers, users etc. - will have a `GUID` assigned.